# How to align Material-UI Menu items?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I use the menu and menu item of material-ui to build a select dropdown menu, but I found one thing strange: the dropdown menu always expand to the left side of the box, as the image shown below:
[image]

I've tried to use the `alignItems` property inside my `<MenuItem>` but it didn't work.

My code is shown below. Can anybody help me to fix this problem? I really appreciate your help!

```
          <Menu
            id="order-menu"
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            keepMounted
            open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
            onClose={() => setAnchorEl(null)}
          >
            {options.map((option, index) => (
              <MenuItem
                key={option}
                selected={index === selectedIndex}
                onClick={(event) => handleMenuItemClick(event, index)}
              >
                {option}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Menu>
```

Comment: I believe, you could apply the required styling to the `root` of the MenuITem component mentioned here https://material-ui.com/api/menu-item/#css with help of MaterialUI core styling approach like here https://material-ui.com/components/menus/#MenuListComposition.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default styles controlling this are in `ListItem` where it specifies [justifyContent: 'flex-start'](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.0/packages/material-ui/src/ListItem/ListItem.js#L16).

You can change this to be right aligned with:

```
const MenuItem = withStyles({
  root: {
    justifyContent: "flex-end"
  }
})(MuiMenuItem);
```

Here's a full working example:

```
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Menu from "@material-ui/core/Menu";
import MuiMenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const MenuItem = withStyles({
  root: {
    justifyContent: "flex-end"
  }
})(MuiMenuItem);

export default function SimpleMenu() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const handleClick = event => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        aria-controls="simple-menu"
        aria-haspopup="true"
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Open Menu
      </Button>
      <Menu
        id="simple-menu"
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}
      >
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>1</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>2</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>3</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>10</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>20</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>300</MenuItem>
      </Menu>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit MenuItem align right]

Related documentation:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content
- https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Got it! Thank you for your help!

Comment: @YunxiuQiu Glad it helped! Please remember to [vote up and accept answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) that solve your problem.

Comment: Oh I see! Sorry I'm not familiar with stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to align the menu

```
anchorOrigin={{
  vertical: 'bottom',
  horizontal: 'center',
}}
transformOrigin={{
  vertical: 'bottom',
  horizontal: 'center',
}}
```

Example

```
<Menu
 id="order-menu"
 anchorEl={anchorEl}
 keepMounted
 open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
 onClose={() => setAnchorEl(null)}
 anchorOrigin={{
   vertical: 'bottom',
   horizontal: 'center',
 }}
 transformOrigin={{
   vertical: 'bottom',
   horizontal: 'center',
 }}
 style={{top: 170}} // you can set top position so that it will show under the selection
>
 {options.map((option, index) => (
   <MenuItem
     key={option}
     selected={index === selectedIndex}
     onClick={(event) => handleMenuItemClick(event, index)}
   >
     {option}
   </MenuItem>
 ))}
```

Answer (score 1):

A more flexible solution to your problem,

use `<ListItemText>` inside `<MenuItem>`
In this way you can style parts of the element.

```
    <MenuItem onClick={handleClose}>
      <ListItemText style={{ paddingRight: 50 }}>undo</ListItemText>
      <ListItemText style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>ctrl+z</ListItemText>
    </MenuItem>
```

example : [shortcut hint on the right](https://codesandbox.io/s/menuitem-align-right-forked-ttkik?file=/demo.js:177-189).

Answer (score 1):

mui 5 could use sx.

```
<MenuItem sx={{ justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
```